# Uppercase and lowercase terminology

Tags: word-choice

Uppercase and lowercase terminology I believe refer to the location of type on a typewriter, as nobody under the age of 35 has seen a typewriter, would it be more correct to use the words letters and capital letters? In a page of type I believe that approximately 97% are letters and approximately 3% are capital letters.

Comment: Their origin is from before the typewriter was invented. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/upper_case) says: **Origin** Referring originally to two type cases positioned on an angled stand, the case containing the capital letters being higher and further away from the compositor. I suppose we could use "small letters" and "big letters" but those are the terms in common use.

Comment: Weather Vane is correct. But I wonder where you got the idea that *case* has anything to do with a typewriter. The shift key moves the strikers (sometimes the platen) up or down, but there are no cases involved.

Comment: So with your proposal if a sign contained only capital letters then you would say that there were no letters on the sign???.

Comment: How old are you?

Comment: I was originally taught to read in the 1950s and "upper case" and "lower case" weren't part of the language for most people  we talked about "capital letters" and "small letters", or sometimes "ordinary letters". It was mainly printers and graphic designers who used  "upper case" and "lower case". These days everyone knows what the terms mean. Another example of the influence of computing on language is the word "font". When I was a child a font was a large basin on a stand in a church and was used for baptisms.

Comment: Wikipedia - [*uppercase / lowercase, more formally **majuscule / minuscule***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case)

Answer (score 3):

Upper/lower case goes back to when typographers set type by hand from lead slugs ("sorts"). Each sort had a single character in a single weight of a typeface at a specific size, like 18 pt. Times Roman. The sorts were kept in sorted in a specific way in drawers, called cases. When a page was being worked on, the two drawers of the font were pulled and laid out on a table. The capital letters' drawer, the upper case, was situated above the lower case.

When a case fell on the floor and the letters flew everywhere, the whole rest of the day would be spent putting everything back where it belongs. That typographer would be pretty angry, or literally out of sorts.

Just because a word derives from technology that's obsolete, that doesn't mean the word is obsolete. If you say young people have never seen a typewriter, I'll bet they've at least seen a picture of one. But it's doubtful the same can be said about a type case drawer, unless they saw one on Pinterest or in an antique store.

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_case

Answer (score 0):

Every expression has a history, once it is in general use.  And some expressions cease to be used because ... well, because enough people use something different.  But there is no reason why an expression '**ought**' to be changed just because of the kind of technological change you mention.

For example, distance at sea still measured in nautical miles, and nautical speeds are measures in 'knots'.  The literal use of a rope with knots at suitable intervals lowered over the side has ceased.  But 'knots' are still used for nautical speed.  There is no reason why they should not be.

Similary, *upper* and *lower* case are still well understood.  Mainly, however, the evolution of language is organic, not driven by rule changes.  If people start to use a different expression and the change catches on, it will.  If it does not catch on , it won't.